# Mongoose splice subdocument array not saving

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following subdocument array called images which itself is contained within an array variants

```
  "_id" : 1
  "variants" : [ 
    {
        "code" : "ajs982-ask19",
        "images" : [ 
            "image1.jpg", 
            "image2.jpg", 
            "image3.jpg"
        ]
    }
```

I'm trying to remove one of the images from the array. I'm using Mongoose but so far I've been unable to remove it.

Assuming that my Schema is called MySchema, I do the following

```
MySchema.findOne({_id:1}, function(err, mySchema){
 myschema.variants[0].images.splice(1, 1);
 myschema.save();
});
```

If I log myschema to the console, I see that the array item at the index position 1 is removed but it is not updated in the database. 
I'd be grateful for any suggestions or recommendations as to how I might remove the item from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$pull` to remove item from child array:

`MySchema.update( {_id: 1}, { $pull: {"variants.0.images": {$in: ["image1.jpg"] } } }` )

Comment: Thanks for the response ema, I tried this but it doesn't update. I should have also said that each variant is itself a separate schema.

Comment: Try again. I was missing the `variants` field

Answer (score 2):

### You need to explicitly tell mongoose that your object has changed.

This is a common gotcha when using Mongoose.

> Why don't my changes to arrays get saved when I update an element
>   directly?
>
> `doc.array[3] = 'changed';`
>
> `doc.save();`
>
> A. Mongoose doesn't create
>   getters/setters for array indexes; without them mongoose never gets
>   notified of the change and so doesn't know to persist the new value.
>   The work-around is to use MongooseArray#set available in Mongoose >=
>   3.2.0.
>
> `doc.array.set(3, 'changed');`
>
> `doc.save();`
>
> // if running a version less than 3.2.0, you must mark the array
>   modified before saving.
>
> `doc.array[3] = 'changed';`
>
> `doc.markModified('array');`
>
> `doc.save();`

The markModified API is still available to use so this should work:

```
MySchema.findOne({_id:1}, function(err, doc){
 doc.variants[0].images.splice(1, 1);
 doc.markModified('variants');
 doc.save();
});
```

Also, if you haven't already done so, some error handling to check where a document came back from your search would be ideal.

Comment: This works very well for me and the implementation is clearer and simpler IMO than the accepted answer.